# Subgroup of the permutation group of $G$. Did I prove this right?

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, permutations, group-homomorphism

Given a group $G$, the automorphism group $Aut(G)$ of $G$ and the permutation group $\sum_G$ of $G$, I have to  prove, that $Aut(G)$ is a subgroup of $\sum_G$.

To do that I must prove:

1. $Aut(G)$ has exactly one neutral element.
2. For each element $\phi$ in $Aut(G)$ there is an inverse element $\phi^{-1}$ in $Aut(G)$
3. Associativity: $\phi\circ (\psi\circ\sigma )=(\phi\circ\psi )\circ\sigma$
4. Closure under composition: If $\phi$ and $\psi$ are automorphisms in $Aut(G)$, then $\phi\circ\psi$ is also an automorphism in $Aut(G)$

**Proof:**

1. The identity map $Id: G\rightarrow G, g\mapsto g$ lies in $Aut(G)$ and is therefore the identity element.
2. Each automorphism $\phi$ in $Aut(G)$ has, by definition, an inverse map $\phi^{-1}$ which also lies in $Aut(G)$. Therefore each element has its inverse.
3. The composition of maps is always associative. (Is this sufficient, or do I have to write more here?)
4. Here, I will use the definition of a homomorphism: $\phi (x\circ y)=\phi (x)*\phi(y):$

$\forall g,h\in G,\forall\phi ,\psi\in Aut(G):(\phi\psi)(gh)=\phi(\psi(gh))=\phi(\psi(g)\psi(h))=\phi(\psi(g))\phi(\psi(h))=(\phi\psi)(g)(\phi\psi)(h)$

Is this proof correct? Also, it seems to me that it is a little bit too long. Are there any things which I can omit? I think 4. is the significant point. Would it suffice if I write just that and leave the other things as implied?

Comment: How do you know that $\phi^{-1}$ is also an automorphism? The proof is not entirely trivial.

Comment: You can go much quicker by using this subgroup caracterisation : let $G$ be a group, and $F \subset G$, then $F$ is a subgroup of $G$ iff $\forall g, h \in F, gh^{-1} \in F$.

Comment: @DavidHill: Doesn't the definition of an isomorphism imply an inverse map? And since we have $G\rightarrow G$ it is the only possibility, I think

Comment: It implies there is an inverse map. Why is this map also an isomorphism?

Comment: @DavidHill: But what else could it be, if it's not an isomorphism? I thought it was the definition, that an isomorphism has an isomorphism as the inverse map.

Comment: Have you ever proved that the inverse of an isomorphism is a homomorphism? If not, now would be a good time.

Comment: @David Hill: I can just apply $\phi$ on both sides, so I get $\phi(\phi^{-1}(gh))=\phi(\phi^{-1}(g)\phi^{-1}(h))$ and so on